# Windows command line args getting to Ruby program only if explicitly invoked as "ruby"

Tags: ruby, windows, command-line, argv, args

I have a Windows 7 machine, and I'm calling a Ruby script from it.  If I do this:

```
ruby Test.rb blah
```

Then ARGV[0] is "blah", as expected.  But if I do this:

```
Test.rb blah
```

Then ARGV[0] is empty.

Do I have to set something up - whether in Windows or in Ruby - to make Ruby receive the command line arguments when it is started implicitly due to the .rb extension, rather than explicitly via typing "ruby"?

Comment: AFAIK Under normal circumstances, that's exactly how it is supposed to work even on Windows. i.e `ruby test.rb blah`

Comment: That's odd. My Windows machine has no problem taking in arguments and I run all my Ruby implicitly.